# Should forecasts from a neural network regression model be constant?

Tags: regression, forecasting, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow

Quick question -

I have built an LSTM RNN model for some data I am trying to forecast.

I've noticed that if I feed my model the same data (after training in order to get a forecast) over and over it generates a different prediction each time. In my head, it SEEMS reasonable that this would happen - I'm not training the model so every time I feed it the data point it hasn't "seen" the data before, and will generate a new (and likely different) prediction each time.

However, I am wondering why. Intuition usually isn't enough for me, and it also seems that if you're traing an LSTM RNN for regression, given a `y` the regression equation should give you the SAME result, not a different one each time. Is there a reason I am noticing this behavior? Could someone link me to some articles or show me why I would be noticing this - perhaps mathematically?

For reference, I am using Tensorflow to generate the model. Since I am still pretty new to the Tensorflow API, I have some doubt due to the different predictions given the same data, and this would go a long way in clearing up my confusion.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

While I've never used LSTM RNN or TensorFlow, from my experience using FFNN for forecasting, the weights for initialization are random each time you run it. This leads to different results for each time you run the model and forecast. You could build the models many times (like 30+ depending on runtime) and average them to get a mean of how the different initialization results produce different models. In R, the way this is avoided is using set.seed()